# Call method of specific MDI child from parent

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MDI parent window that can contain mulitple instances of a particular child from, call it **frmChild**. Now when a particular control is clicked from the parent, I need to get the active frmChild and **invoke a particular method from frmChild**

Below is an image of what I am trying to achieve (get active MDI child and invoke a particular method from that class):

[image: a busy cat]

Now each frmChild is instantiated by:

```
private void newFileToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmNewDocument = new frmNewDocument();
        frmNewDocument.MdiParent = this;
        frmNewDocument.Show();
    }
```

When I want to invoke a method from the **active frmChild**, I am trying the following and am stuck:

```
private void saveFileToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* get active MDI child*/
        Form frmActiveNewDocument = this.ActiveMdiChild;           
        
        /* make sure MDI child is a "New Document" type form */
        if (frmActiveNewDocument.GetType() == frmNewDocument.GetType())
        {
            /* invoke a method from active frmChild here */
        }
    }
```

I am still learning OOP and am sure this is some principle. If that can be mentioned in the article, that would be great also.

**Note: I read that an interference for frmChild is the best way to approach this issue so the Main form doesn't need to go digging around in each frmChild, so I have created an interface that frmChild uses, which is: **

```
 public interface NewFileFormInterface
{
    void saveFile();
}
```

Now, **saveFile()** is the  method I want to invoke from Main, which is implemented in frmChild.

Any help on this issue and some keywords I can research would be great.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
frmNewDocument child = ActiveMdiChild as frmNewDocument;
if (child != null)
{
    child->saveFile();
}
```

The as keyword performs a run-time cast. If the object (ActiveMdiChild in this case) is null or is not of the as type, the result will be null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

You might also be interested in reading:
[.Net Naming Convention Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While this helped and is a possible solution, is there a way use the interface instead of the actual form? Sorry if this doesn't make sense, but I am just confused at the moment. I'd like to keep everything as loosely coupled as possible.

Comment: Yes, use `NewFileFormInterface` rather than `frmNewDocument`, assuming that the child form implements that interface.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Yes all **frmNewDocument** classes implement the **NewFileFormInterface** Thanks for the links also. I'll give them a read.

Comment: The link I gave for naming guidelines is "down one level". I've corrected it to the higher level document, though you probably already noticed this in the navigation pane to the left.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if (ActiveMdiChild is frmNewDocument)
{
    (ActiveMdiChild as frmNewDocument).saveFile();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this has always worked for me.

In the Child code:

```
public void SaveFile()
{
  // Some code goes here.
}
```

And in the Parent code:

```
frmNewDocument child = this.ActiveMdiChild as frmNewDocument;
if(child != null)
{
  child.SaveFile();
}
```

Hope this helps someone else who is looking for a more concise answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way. "AuditAddMod" is a form. I have parallel children. There is a public "PassData()" method in that form that is called and does what I need in the sibling form.

```
private void LoadRelatedFollowUpAuditTable()
{
   foreach (Form form in this.MdiParent.MdiChildren)
   {
      if (form.Name == "AuditAddMod" && form.Text != this.Text)
      {
         ((AuditAddMod)form).PassData(form.Name, 1);
      }
   }
}
```